# Ansible - test if command output is missing items

Tags: ansible

I have a list of strings that I expect in some command's output.
How can I create an ansible script that tests and - in case one or several of the entries is not contained - executes a task?

So my ansible script might look like:

```
vars:
  musthave:
    - value1
    - value2
tasks:
- name: Check the configured values
  command: "cat configfile"
  register: current_configuration
  changed_when: false

- set a variable if one or more of the musthave's are missing in current_configuration.stdout
  ...

- name: Execute task to reconfigure system
  command: "reconfigure..."
  when: true = variable
```

So is there something like

```
variable = false
for s in musthave:
    if not s in current_configuration.stdout:
        variable |= true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original request was looking to check for existence of specific values that may appear somewhere in the command's output. Preparing a list for `difference` to work is a disadvantage, the side effect is that you can calculate the difference in both directions.

So now I can not only check for missing entries but also for those that are too much.

```
- name: print hostvars
  debug:
    var: hostvars[{{ ansible_host }}]['certificate_domains']

- name: print certificate
  delegate_to: silver.fritz.box
  command: "openssl x509 -in /home/hiran/homeserver.crt -noout -text"
  register: certificate

- name: grab subject's common name and alternative names
  set_fact:
    commonName: "{{ certificate.stdout | regex_search('Subject.*CN\\s=\\s([\\.a-zA-Z]+)', '\\1') }}"
    altNames: "{{ certificate.stdout | regex_findall('DNS:([\\.a-zA-Z]+)') }}"
- name: prepare the lists so they can be subtracted from each other
  set_fact:
    contained: "{{ (commonName + altNames) | unique }}"
    musthave: "{{ hostvars[{{ ansible_host }}]['certificate_domains'] | unique }}"
- name: calculate differences
  set_fact:
    missing: "{{ musthave | difference(contained) }}"
    toomuch: "{{ contained | difference(musthave) }}"

- name: show difference
  debug:
    msg: Something is wrong
  when: (missing | length)>0 or (toomuch | length)>0
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you don't need an intermediate variable. According to the [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory), use the `difference` filter to select the difference between your list of must have values  and the output of your config file.

```
vars:
  musthave:
    - value1
    - value2

tasks:
- name: Check the configuration values
  command: "seq -f 'value%g' 2 1 5"
  register: current_configuration
  changed_when: false

- debug: var=current_configuration.stdout_lines

- name: Execute task to reconfigure system
  debug: msg="{{ musthave | difference(current_configuration.stdout_lines) }}"
  when: musthave | difference(current_configuration.stdout_lines)
```

The last task `debug` is executed only if the difference is not empty.

Comment: Using the difference operator is the best solution I saw so far but it requires to have lists of items to subtract from each other. While this is true for `musthave`, in my case `current_configuration.stdout_lines` was not, so I had to hammer this into a suitable list.